# HTML Email Background Color

Tags: html, css, background, html-email

I created a HTML mail and edit css. It's good now. But, i want give background color my window.

My code:

```
<body bgcolor="#f2f2f2" leftmargin="0" topmargin="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0">
```

But don't work. When i a table, my structure crash.

```
<table bgcolor="#f2f2f2">
--
My Email Structure
**
</table>
```

How can i fix it?

Tested browsers:

Firefox,
Safari,
Chrome.

Tested client:

Gmail

Comment: In before animated GIFs.

Comment: @KyleSevenoaks — HTML formatted email lives in 1998.

Comment: "When i a table, my structure crash" — How do you "a table"? What precisely happens when you structure "crash"?

Comment: How are you testing this HTML? What email clients? What browsers? What QA tools? Does it fail everywhere?

Comment: Again, what does "crash" mean in this context? Are you testing the HTML directly in those browsers or only by sending the email to GMail and then loading GMail in those browsers?

Comment: You should definitely check out some of the articles in this page http://www.campaignmonitor.com/resources/will-it-work/ ..and others throughout the website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<table style="background-color: #f2f2f2;">

</table>
```

The bgcolor attribute of  is **deprecated** in HTML 4.01.

A deprecated element or attribute is one that has been outdated.

Deprecated elements may become obsolete in the future, but browsers should continue to support deprecated elements for backward compatibility.

Answer (score -2):

Try the css

```
 body {background-color:#f2f2f2;}
```

background-color must work.
[Reference here](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_background.asp)

Comment: Email clients are notoriously poor about supporting `<style>` elements.

Comment: And moreover http://w3fools.com/ is always a good reminder.